# View invalidation?

Tags: android, view

I found a snippet in Android source that offsets a view's top and bottom by an offset amount as follows:

```
static void offsetTopAndBottom(View view, int offset) {
        final int currentTop = view.getTop();
        view.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);

        if (offset != 0) {
            // We need to manually invalidate pre-honeycomb
            final ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof View) {
                final int absOffset = Math.abs(offset);
                ((View) parent).invalidate(
                        view.getLeft(),
                        currentTop - absOffset,
                        view.getRight(),
                        currentTop + view.getHeight() + absOffset);
            } else {
                view.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unable to understand the part: `if (parent instanceof View) {`.

First, I expect the parent of a View to be a `ViewGroup` or null. Why would having a `View` parent make sense?

Second, why is view `invalidate()` called differently for the two cases?

Comment: it less expensive to invalidate only a part than the whole

Comment: **To the downvoter**: Could you kindly let me know the reason for downvoting?

Comment: @pulp_fiction agree.

Comment: see [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java) for example

Comment: @pskink : Thanks. I figured it out.(posted an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Thanks to @pskink for the example.

Here is the thing: The View class has a set of `invalidate()` methods having a default implementation to invalidate itself. The above code makes the assumption that if any subclass of `View` which is also a `ViewParent`(*which doesn't mean another normal view; it has to be a container*) **if** wants to provide their own implementation of invalidating children by overriding any of the `invalidate()` methods from `View` class, they can quite happily do so. We are taking care of just calling that implementation here.(*just in case thing*) Also, `ViewParent` is provided the dirty `Rect`(i.e, the `View` child) to invalidate:

```
if (parent instanceof View) {
    final int absOffset = Math.abs(offset);
    ((View) parent).invalidate(
        view.getLeft(),
        currentTop - absOffset,
        view.getRight(),
        currentTop + view.getHeight() + absOffset);
}
```

But instead, if there is no *such* parent, we might as well ask the view to invalidate itself:

```
else {
    view.invalidate();
}
```

In both the cases, there is no optimization as to invalidate only part of `View` because the operation is for offsetting the `View`, i.e, shifting the View, thereby making the entire `View` dirty. `ViewParent` just needs to know which `Rect` the dirty View lies in and that is what we have provided in the if part.